# Disabling Apple Pay in iOS 9 simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

The Apple Pay capability in the iOS 9 simulator is a welcome addition.  But I don't see a way to turn Apple Pay off so that I can test how my app behaves when Apple Pay is not available or not set up yet to make payments.

Has anyone found controls in the iOS 9 simulator to turn Apple Pay off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not supported.  Please file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com

For now, can you use a simulated device that does not support Apple Pay?